# Move single element to the end of a flex container

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, flexbox

I thought that I'd be able to shift this single button to the end of a flex-box.

I have set the parent to be a `display: flex;` and then I thought that I'd be able to target one element and pin it to the bottom of the container with `align-self: flex-end;`

It doesn't work. Here is my pen: [My Codepen illustrating the issue](http://codepen.io/joshsmith01/pen/XJoEKM)

```
 <div class="row services">
  <div class="small-3 panel columns service">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
    <h3>SUSPENDISSE</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, ad?</p>
    <div class="button">Read More</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-3 panel columns service">
    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
    <h3>MAECENAS</h3><p>Porro quibusdam nostrum eaque, quasi laudantium delectus quaerat cumque, quos.</p>
    <div class="button">Read More</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-3 panel columns service">
    <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
    <h3>ALIQUAM</h3><p>Iste architecto omnis, esse facere quod ratione, officia veritatis fugit.</p>
    <div class="button">Read More</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-3 panel columns service">
    <i class="fa fa-flask"></i>
    <h3>HABITASSE</h3><p>Ducimus voluptates assumenda, illum adipisci sed quaerat est ipsum nisi.</p>
    <div class="button">Read More</div>
  </div>
</div>

.services {
  display: flex;

}
.service {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.button {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`align-self` will only work with direct child elements of a flex parent, so:

- Make `.service` a flex parent with `display: flex` and set `flex-wrap: wrap`
- Center the button with `margin: 0 auto`

### Working Example

Also [available as a Codepen.](http://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/xbmeQo)

```css
.services {
  display: flex;
}
.service {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.button {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin: 0 auto !important; 
  /* !important used for this example only to override foundation.css*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row services">
  <div class="small-3 panel columns service">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
    <h3>SUSPENDISSE</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, ad?</p>
    <div class="button">Read More</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-3 panel columns service">
    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
    <h3>MAECENAS</h3><p>Porro quibusdam nostrum eaque, quasi laudantium delectus quaerat cumque, quos.</p>
    <div class="button">Read More</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-3 panel columns service">
    <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
    <h3>ALIQUAM</h3><p>Iste architecto omnis, esse facere quod ratione, officia veritatis fugit.</p>
    <div class="button">Read More</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-3 panel columns service">
    <i class="fa fa-flask"></i>
    <h3>HABITASSE</h3><p>Ducimus voluptates assumenda, illum adipisci sed quaerat est ipsum nisi.</p>
    <div class="button">Read More</div>
  </div>
</div>
```